# pandas DataFrame.hist() function not showing axes titles with setting figsize

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot histogram from my DataFrame using the hist() function, with a given figsize.

```
my_df.hist(bins=50, layout=(4, 2), figsize=(100, 100))
```

However, somehow the axes titles are lost. I wonder if someone has similar problems and can help?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you mean? Did you try `tight_layout` on the figure?

Comment: figsize(100, 100) creates a very big picture, that exceeds common screen size. If you reduce the window size to fit the screen, can you see axes titles?

Comment: [**docs**](https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html) *figsize
w,h tuple in inches* That's 100 inches by 100 inches.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum supported figure size is 50 inch, i.e. `figsize=(50,50)`. 
So you need to restrict yourself to this size.

When using a big figure like that, the axes are not lost. They may however be out of the screen.

In order to make sure the axes titles (if there are actually any) are within the figure, you may use `pyplot.tight_layout`.

In order to make sure the figure is within the screen or plotting area of the backend in use, consider using a reasonable figure size like `(13,8)` or so.